# Azure AD run application at startup

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have an **azure active directory** setup in my company

what i want to do is to run **exe** or **PowerShell** file when any user login using his azure ad account on his computer

because there is an application we must use at work and it should be run at every device on the company

i did search on this issue but i didn't find any useful solution

so is this is possible

Comment: Do you mean login to the OS/computer using AD credentials? In which case, you can look into this https://www.thewindowsclub.com/run-windows-powershell-scripts-first

Comment: i think this solution cannot be applied because there is a lot of devices and i want to do it without interacting with the device itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition can be addressed with MS Intune provided you should have license for it.

MS Intune integrates with Azure AD to manage devices and user based on your custom organization policy. You must enroll your devices in MS Intune MDM for the Startup/logon PowerShell Script to be run on those devices. Devices must run Windows 10 version 1709 or later. The Devices should be Azure AD joined and enrolled with auto enrolment or manual enrolled policy.

> The Microsoft Intune Management Extension is a service that runs on
> the device, just like any other service listed in the Services app
> **(services.msc)**. After a device reboots, this service may also restart,
> and check for any assigned PowerShell scripts with the Intune service.
> If the Microsoft Intune Management Extension service is set to Manual,
> then the service may not restart after the device reboots

Would suggest you follow this MS document to get to know what would be the
Prerequisites and create a script policy and assign it devices.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/apps/intune-management-extension

Comment: is this solution needs a physicals interaction with the device or it's all from the Azure portal

Comment: its Not required, you can do it from azure portal itself by setting up auto enrolment for devices joined or register with Azure AD. User need to sync his device with Management Gateway Server to download all the policies of Intune.

Comment: how can the user sync his device with Management Gateway Server

Comment: Under your Device Setting->Account->Access Work&School ->Connected to MS Azure Ad info->Device Sync Status -Sync. to Sync all the policies which is assigned through the MDM(Intune). To sync your Devices through Intune management portal kindly refer the below link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/remote-actions/device-sync

Comment: is it required for the devices to be in the "Intune enrolled devices" ?

Comment: Yes it is require because the all policy is uploaded or created in Intune itself.